# how to test the significance of a multivariate, multiple regression model as a whole

Tags: r, multiple-regression, manova

I have a dataset with seven dependent variables and three independent variables. Now I want to test the significance of a multivariate regression model as a whole.

My model looks like this (using r):

```
my.model <- lm(cbind(res1,res2,res3,res4,res5,res6,res7) ~ indep1 + indep2+indep1:indep2, data=df)
```

now I can use

```
summary(manova(my.model))
```

for model testing. I am not sure about this,  how can I interpret the results when I want to test the model as a whole?

this is result of the summary:

```
                 Df   Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
indep1           1 0.067716   35.383      7   3410 < 2.2e-16 ***
indep2           1 0.209308  128.954      7   3410 < 2.2e-16 ***
indep1:indep2    1 0.006977    3.422      7   3410  0.001191 ** 
Residuals                 3416
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can compare you model with a Null model such as `lm(cbind(res1,res2,res3,res4,res5,res6,res7) ~ 1, data=df)` using the `anova` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use summary.aov() function to check individual responses but model as a whole can be tested with summary() - function which is used for manova - object.

Its output can be Wilks lambda statistic or Pillai test statistic. It produces individual IV level significanses.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added the result of the summary() I used. Are these the statistics I can use for the multivariate model testing?

Comment: @user1983395 At least you can test variable significances across models.